# UIScrollView Delegate Method Is Not Firing

Tags: ios, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have added a ScrollView as a subview and confirm its delegate.

```
contentView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
contentView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
contentView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
contentView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:contentView];
```

All is working fine. But when I scroll very fast and rapidly, delegate methods are not fired.

```
scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
```

Don't know why is this happening?

Comment: Could it be because the scrollview is still scrolling at this point? Those methods will only be fired when the scrolling comes to a complete halt.

Comment: Scrollview stucks after calling `didScroll:` and other delegates methods are not firing